# Amazon SES SMTP with Django

Tags: python, django, smtp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to use Amazon's new SMTP service for SES with Django 1.3.1 but I'm not having much luck.

I've created my SES SMTP credentials and have this in my settings:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my-smtp-user'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my-smtp-password'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
```

Then I try sending a test email (from and to verified email addresses):

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Test subject', 'This is the body', 'info@abc.com',['hello@abc.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

But I get the following error:

```
SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

I can telnet to the server:

```
telnet email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 465
```

Comment: Could be related to amazon not supporting start_tls. "The Amazon SES SMTP interface currently requires the Handshake Protocol and does not support STARTTLS. We support both SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0."  See discussion here [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=82510&tstart=0&start=0)

Comment: @mtnpaul thanks but this article isn't for SMTP. I specifically wanted to use the SMTP protocol. But it does sound like the issue is related to TLS not being supported, even though they mention it in the console.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found a much simpler solution that would allow me to use Django's built-in mail classes so I can still get my admin error email reports etc.

Thanks to this little beauty I was able to use SES SMTP without any problems:

https://github.com/bancek/django-smtp-ssl

Download and install (python setup.py install)

Then just change your settings to use this new email backend:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
```

The rest of the settings are as per normal:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_smtp_username'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_smtp_password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: Since your using a SSL backend, do you really need to set EMAIL_USE_TLS = True ?

Comment: Setting EMAIL_USE_TLS = False doesn't make a difference.

Comment: this answer is extremely out of date. You can simply use the built in django configuration to do this now.

Answer (score 16):

### Aug, 2022 Update with Django-3.2.4:

**No libraries needed such as `django-ses` or `django-amazon-ses` !!**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_smtp_username'      # Must create SMTP Credentials
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_smtp_password'  # Must create SMTP Credentials
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myses@sender.com' # If don't need, comment out!!
```

I added **`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`**.

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myses@sender.com'
```

If you don't need it, comment it out!!

```
# DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myses@sender.com'
```

Moreover, for **`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`**, put one **`verified domain`** or **`email address`** whether or not your account is in the **`sandbox`**.

So for the verified domain **`sender.com`** below,

[image]

---

Three of them below are valid: (Use only one of three)

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'abc@sender.com' # OR
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'test@sender.com' # OR
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myses@sender.com'
```

But these two below are not valid: (These give you error)

*The format must be **`something@sender.com`** !!

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'sender.com' 
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '@sender.com'
```

Then, for the verified **`2 email addresses`** below,

[image]

---

Just use only one of two below:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'hello@gmail.com' # OR
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'world@outlook.com'
```

Finally, for **`EMAIL_HOST_USER`** and **`EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`**, you must create **`SMTP Credentials`**.

Choose **`SMTP Settings`**:

[image]

---

Press **`Create My SMTP Credentials`** Button:

[image]

---

Given **`SMTP Credentials`**:

[image]

Then, put the **`SMTP Credentials`** as below:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'AKIAWP3TMGZN4OZH5H37'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'BB6dufiw96jJHUTrowXI8R4gcyOI+t1+Skbi51cdHYhV'
```

*(I've already deleted these **`SMTP Credentials`**)

---

Answer (score 13):

**2019 Update: Django 2.2.1**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_smtp_username'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_smtp_password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

> No library needed.

Credits : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32476190/5647272

Reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/

Answer (score 11):

Since Django 1.7, you can send email with SSL natively without third party library.

```
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-EMAIL_USE_SSL)

Comment: bear in mind: `ValueError` EMAIL_USE_TLS/EMAIL_USE_SSL are mutually exclusive, so only set one of those settings to True.

Answer (score 5):

After long long searching and trying I found:

Instead using:

```
 s = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
 s.starttls()
 s.login(user, password)
```

For AmazonSES SMTP must be:

```
 s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host, port)
 s.login(user, password)
```

So, I think, for django you can either fix django code, or write you own simple email backend [based on default django email backend].

**UPD**:

I found another solution (but not tested it by myself): use SSLEmailBackend from link below

```
// settings.py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'backends.smtp.SSLEmailBackend'
```

(From here: [Mysterious issue with Django + uWSGI + send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549371/mysterious-issue-with-django-uwsgi-send-email) )

**UPD2**:

AmazonSES supports STARTTLS from now :)

> Amazon SES supports expanded attachment types, VERP, and STARTTLS for SMTP

(from Amazon Newsletter)

Comment: Not sure what that backend it but it doesn't come with Django out of the box. See my similar solution below.

Comment: (Also, I forgot to mention beautiful django-ses app :))

Answer (score 1):

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2405502737055650

core python functionality sample

Answer (score 1):

I took like 3 hrs breaking my head over it. Your solution about the smtplib with s.starttls() and then s.login() is good with a python program with all the email credentials in the same file. But I don't think it is a clean way to do it in Django. So I finally figured it out. Irrespective of whether your machine is a 32 or a 64 bit. Just do the following steps:

1. Install boto

   > pip install --upgrade boto
2. Install django-ses

   > pip install django-ses
3. In your djando settings.py file update the following info.

   > EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
   >   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'your_username'
   >   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'your_password'
4. In your django file where you want to send an email

   > from django.core.mail import send_mail 
   >   send_mail('Test subject', 'This is the body', 'info@abc.com',['hello@abc.com'],fail_silently=False)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried smtp settings in order to @Givp(who answered above), I want to give complete AWS SMTP settings in django.

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'admin@domain.com'

ADMINS = [('name', 'name@domain.com')]
MANAGERS = ADMINS

SERVER_EMAIL = 'admin@domain.com' # this is for to send 500 mail to admins

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
MAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' 
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'Accesskeyofsmtp'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'secretkeyofsmtp'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Here we have to verify all the mail-ids before sending email.then everything would work as our expectation

Comment: This does not work for me. I never receive an email.