# Django & Amazon SES SMTP. Cannot send email

Tags: python, django, smtp, amazon-ses

this is my settings.py :

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '465'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config_data['EMAIL_HOST_USER']
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config_data['EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD']
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

I have verified the email addresses and have also generated SMTP credentials which I downloaded the credentials containing the IAM username, Smtp username, Smtp password. I used the smtp username for EMAIL_HOST_USER and smtp password for EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD.

In django, I sent an email with this line (admin@admin.com is replaced with a gmail account that is in the verified email list) :

```
send_mail("Subject", "content", "admin@admin.com", [email], fail_silently=False)
```

That did not work. Sending a test email from the SES console (select one of the email in verified emails and click send a test email button) works though.

This [document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-client-command-line.html) says that I can send email via command line with openssl command. So, i did ssh to the EC2 machine, and use :

```
openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -starttls smtp -connect email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:25
```

Notice that i used 25 here, when i used port 465, it outputed :

```
didn't found starttls in server response, try anyway...
write:errno=32
```

So instead I tried port 25, It connected (250 OK) and then I typed :

```
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
SMTP_USER
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
SMTP_PASSWORD
```

but it outputted : 535 Authentication Credentials Invalid. Could it be I used a wrong credentials? but I copy the username and password straight from the smtp user and password generation page.

I also tried to attach AmazonSESFullAccess policy to all of the IAM users but nothing happened.

I use the Django 1.8.2. Tried Django-ses but it did not work too (syntax error when running the tests, it does not support python 3?)

**UPDATE**

I changed the port to 587 and use USE_TLS True and now I can send_mail from django shell. I put the function in my app views.py :

```
def test_email(request):
  send_mail("title", "content", "abc@gmail.com", ["def@gmail.com"], fail_silently=False)
  return get_return_object(request, status_code=1)
```

and in urls.py I put this inside the urlpatterns :

```
url(r'^test_email/$', views.test_email, name="test_email"),
```

and when I visited the URL, nothing happens. I call the same function test_email from the shell and it works.

**UPDATE**

It turns out that I can also use port 465 and USE_SSL True and be able to send_mail from django shell. but still it does not work in views.py

Comment: Would you please put the error message? Try to generate new credentials.

Comment: please see the updated section. I changed the port, and now i can send mail from shell but for some reason, i can not send it through url

Answer (score 3):

If you use port 465:
Install django-smtp-ssl using pip

```
pip install django-smtp-ssl
```

then change EMAIL_BACKEND in settings.py as follows:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
```

If you use port 587:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Answer (score 3):

**2020 update**

As the documentation says here: [Django Email Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/) and [Email_use_ssl](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-EMAIL_USE_SSL)

I am using Django 3.0 at this moment, and the documentation says that you can use

```
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

> ...  It is generally used on port 465

I make my think works and send emails using ***AWS SES***  and ***port*** **465** service using that line instead EMAIL_USE_TLS = True :)